# Bidi text display

Tags: css, jsp, struts2, bidi

We want to display text in our application which sometimes contain a mix of both rtl and ltr. I am able to determine the language of the text and can switch dir=ltr or dir=rtl depending on the language.

The problem arises when the same sentence hadboth english and an arabic text, in which case my language detection detects arabic(since primary language) and dir=rtl is selected. How can i display these mixed sentences

Regards, 
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

The `dir` attribute sets the directionality of directionally neutral text. It does not affect normal text in Latin or Arabic letters; they follow their inherent strong directionality. Well, at least they should. Browsers have bugs, and setting `dir` may help *if* you know which directionality should be set. Moreover, setting `dir` sets the overall layout direction; e.g., if you have Arabic text with some English text inside it (schematically, Ar1 followed by En followed by Ar2, in the simplest case), you should set `dir=rtl` to get things right (in the example, Ar1 first, on the right, then En to the left of it, and then Ar2 last, i.e. leftmost).

But problems arise when directionally ambiguous characters like parentheses are involved, e.g. when English text inside Arabic text has “Hello world (42).”. Inside a block with `dir=rtl`, this gets rendered as “(Hello world (42 .”

To deal with this, you need to recognize the English-language fragment too, and wrap it inside an element for which you set embedded directionality:

```
<style>
.ltr { unicode-bidi: embed; direction: ltr; }
</style>
[...]
<p dir=rtl>
مرحبا العالم. <span class=ltr>Hello world (42).</span> وكان هذا الاختبار.</p>
```